# Notation pedantry (integration by substitution)?

Tags: calculus, notation, integration

In a summative assessment, I lost a mark due to this:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty  y^2\exp\left\{-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\lambda x\right)y^2\right\} \; dy$$

Now let $a=\frac{1}{2}+\lambda x$ for brevity and $u=ay^2$ so $du=2ay \; du$

Then

$$f_X(x)=\frac{2\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty \frac{u}{a} e^{-u} \; du.$$

The comment was "show that you have considered any possible change in limits", and "y=" and "u=" were inserted into my script, so that it now reads:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{y=-\infty}^{y=\infty} y^2\exp\left\{-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\lambda x\right)y^2\right\} \; dy$$

Then

$$f_X(x)=\frac{2\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{u=0}^{u=\infty}\frac{u}{a} e^{-u} \; du.$$

This is not a calculus module (it's statistical theory, final year undergraduate), and I feel pretty hard done by ! Is this overly pedantic on the part of the marker ?

EDIT, rather than correct the typos in this post, which would obscure robjohn's answer, I have posted an answer which (hopefully) doesn't contain any typos and makes the point more clearly.

Comment: What I would complain about is that you wrote $\exp-(1/2 +\lambda x)y^2$ while, as is it seems, you wanted to write $\exp(-(1/2 +\lambda x)y^2)$. I would not change your mark because of this, though.

Comment: @Thomas, sorry, yes, a stupid typo. Please see my "answer" below.

Comment: @PSellaz: I think you should speak with your instructor and/or the marker.  They are setting the marking scheme for this class, and you need to have a better sense of their expectations than you have.  Our opinions here are not terribly relevant. (I haven't looked at your specific work, so this is far from an answer.)

Comment: Please: Don't write \text{exp}.  Write \exp.  The latter not only prevents italicization, but provides proper spacing before and after "exp", thus: $a\exp b$.  \exp is a standard operator name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your marker was not suggesting that you should write the $y=$ and $u=$ signs on the integrals (I like to do that myself, but there's no reason you should as it's perfectly clear from the $d y$ and the $du$ that those are the variables being integrated over).  Rather, (s)he was trying to point out that you should have inserted an extra step noting explicitly that $y=\infty$ corresponds to $u=\infty$ and that $y=-\infty$ corresponds to $u=0$ - considering that this is an undergraduate course, I don't really see why you should have put this in since it seems perfectly clear and you did put the right limits into the integrals, so I would feel a little hard done by as well.

Comment: Thanks. I agree that it's quite a useful thing to do, to avoid making errors with the limits. In fact I might take up the habit of doing it, for this very reason ! Writing a line to explain the new limits seems reasonable but hardly /essential/ in a module like this. Another reason I think the marking is pointlessly strict is that I can't recall this has never been mentioned in a lecture, nor is it done anywhere in the lecture notes.

Comment: Yes - it does seem pointlessly strict.  You might want to think about showing the script to your lecturer or someone, just in case there's some other reason you lost that mark.

Comment: In light of the above, should I delete this answer now?

Comment: No, the answer is fine. Thanks. Although I made a couple of typos in my post, the point was still the y= and u=

Answer (score 8):

This is *not* pedantic! The marker is trying to point out where you went wrong.

I will assume that your integral is actually
$$
\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2e^{-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2}\mathrm{d}y\tag{1}
$$
First of all, if $u=ay^2$ and $y=-\infty$, it would seem that $u=\infty$, not $0$.

Secondly, if you are going to use $u=ay^2$, you should break up the integral into pieces that will have disjoint domains. Note that under $u=ay^2$ both $(-\infty,0]$ and $[0,\infty)$ get mapped to $[0,\infty)$. To prevent confusion, the integral should first be broken up into
$$
\small
\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2e^{-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2}\mathrm{d}y
=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^0 y^2e^{-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2}\mathrm{d}y
+\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty y^2e^{-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2}\mathrm{d}y\tag{2}
$$
One might then notice that since $y^2e^{-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2}$ is even, the two integrals on the right in $(2)$ are equal, therefore
$$
\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2e^{-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2}\mathrm{d}y
=\frac{2\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty y^2e^{-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2}\mathrm{d}y\tag{3}
$$
Finally, we can apply $u=ay^2$:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{2\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty y^2e^{-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2}\mathrm{d}y
&=\frac{2\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{a}e^{-u}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2ay}\\
&=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{a}e^{-u}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{au}}\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Note the correct translation of $\mathrm{d}y$. Therefore, the substitution *should* yield
$$
\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2e^{-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2}\mathrm{d}y
=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty\frac{u}{a}e^{-u}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{au}}\tag{5}
$$

Comment: This is the correct $f_X(x)=c/(\lambda x+\frac12)^{3/2}$. Note that $f_X$ is integrable at $+\infty$, as it should as the density of a random variable (while the OP's suggestion $f_X(x)=c/(\lambda x+\frac12)$ is not).

Comment: The lower limit went to 0 in my script because of symmetry (note the factor of 2 outside the 2nd integral). 
I did forget the $1/\sqrt{au}$ in my post (it was correct in my script. I just forgot it in the posting above).
So, I got correct answer. I just lost a mark regarding the y= and the u= .

Comment: [sigh] Sorry, yes, the original integral in my OP is wrong as it should be $\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 \text{exp}(-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2)\mathrm{d}y\tag{1}$

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, this is my complete answer to the question:

$$f_X(x)=\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty y^2 \text{exp}(-(1/2+\lambda x)y^2)\mathrm{d}y$$

Let $a=\frac{1}{2}+\lambda x$ for brevity and $u=ay^2$ so $du=2ay \mathrm{ d}y$. Then

$$f_X(x)=\frac{2\lambda}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u}{a} e^{-u} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sqrt{au}}$$

using the symmetry of the integrand. So

$$
\begin{align}
f_X(x) 

&= \frac{\lambda a^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}u^{\frac{3}{2}-1}e^u \mathrm{d}u\\
&= \frac{\lambda a^{-\frac{3}{2}}\Gamma(3/2)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\\
&= \frac{\lambda}{2 \sqrt{2}(\frac{1}{2}+\lambda x)^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{align}
$$

I got 6 out of 7 marks - with 1 mark deducted for not writing y= and u= in the integration limits, and this is what my OP was about - I'm sorry for the typos in the OP !

Comment: You could always try opening his post for editing and seeing yourself!  Otherwise, it's a \$\$ on both sides of an equation to make it appear big and in the centre, and a $\backslash$begin{align} ... $\backslash$end{align} within the two $$s together with an & before each equals sign and a \\ wherever you want to start a new line if you want the equals signs to line up.  I've edited your post now so that the formatting is as in @robjohn's answer - if you have further questions, post them on the meta.

Comment: @Donkey_2009, thank you !